# Pattern matching runtime.universe.Type with Option

Tags: scala

I have a List called

```
val types : List[runtime.universe.Type]
```

Now I want to match the `types(j)` with `Option` of any type.

Like this,

```
if(types(j) =:= typeOf[Option[AnyVal]]) {
```

I tried

```
typeOf[Option[_]], typeOf[Option[Any]]
```

But none of these are matching.

How to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=:=` matches only when the two type are equivalent, and, e.g. `Option[String]` and `Option[Any]` are not equivalent.

You should use `<:<` instead:

```
if(types(j) <:< typeOf[Option[Any]]) {
```

Comment: But this will be true for `Some[Any]`, `None.type`, `Nothing`, not just "Option of any type".

Comment: That's true.  Add a 'lower bound' to the test if you want to limited to Option only: `if((types(j) <:< typeOf[Option[Any]]) && (typeOf[Option[Nothing]] <:< types(j))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `typeSymbol` to match an `Option` with any type.  You can also just use `==` on a type if you want an exact match like just matching on `Option[Any]`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

val types = List(ru.typeOf[Option[String]], 
                 ru.typeOf[Option[Any]], 
                 ru.typeOf[String])

// matches any Option and prints true true false
types.foreach(t => println(t.typeSymbol == ru.typeOf[Option[_]].typeSymbol))

// matches only Option[Any] and prints false true false
types.foreach(t => println(t == ru.typeOf[Option[Any]]))
```